# How to set active tools in Holoviews

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, holoviews

Sometimes my plots get drawn with the `pan` tool active and sometimes they draw with `pan` and `wheel_zoom` active. I'd like to force `wheel_zoom` to be active upon rendering. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Since holoviews 1.11.0 was released the original answer has been outdated. HoloViews now has an explicit option to set the active tool(s), called `active_tools` which accepts a list of tool names or instances, e.g. to activate the `wheel_zoom` tool by default you would do this:

```
 hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]).options(active_tools=['wheel_zoom'])
```

The rest of the answer below is outdated:

For any options that are not directly exposed in HoloViews you can define hooks which can directly modify the bokeh models. Here is a simple example that defines a hook to set the active scroll tool (as described [in the bokeh docs)](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#setting-the-active-tools):

```
def set_active_tool(plot, element):
    plot.state.toolbar.active_scroll = plot.state.tools[2]

hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]).options(finalize_hooks=[set_active_tool])
```

Setting the active tool seems like a fairly common action though, so filing an issue to request that the active tools can be declared directly as a plot option would be appreciated.

Comment: You can also set this option for all Curves with `hv.opts.defaults(hv.opts.Curve(active_tools=["wheel_zoom"]))`. What I got here looking for, however, is whether you can set it for all Elements.