# How to control (active) tools in holoviews with bokeh backend

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

How do I control which tools are used / active in a `holoviews` plot with the `bokeh` backend? I've seen [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416512/4880003), but that only *adds* a new active tool; it doesn't keep any other tools (e.g. pan) from being active.

For a specific example, suppose I only want the hover tool. I would try doing this:

```py
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh")
hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]).opts(tools=["hover"])
```

but then I end up with a plot that has hover *in addition* to the default tools. How do I specify the list of *all* tools that I want to use, so that no tools are used that aren't in that list?

[image: plot with too many tools]

Similarly, how do I specify the list of *all* active tools? E.g.

```py
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh")
hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]).opts(tools=["hover"], active_tools=[])
```

gives me both pan and hover being active; I want hover to be the only tool but no tool to be active.

[image: plot with too many active tools]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, use `default_tools` option:

```
hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]).opts(tools=["hover"], default_tools=[])
```

fot the second question, there is not method in holoviews to do this, but you can set it to the `Figure` object directly:

```
def set_tools(plot, element):
    plot.state.toolbar.active_drag = None

hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]).opts(finalize_hooks=[set_tools])
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, at the moment the following tools are possible:

> box_edit, box_select, box_zoom, click, crosshair, help, hover,
>   lasso_select, pan, point_draw, poly_draw, poly_edit, poly_select,
>   previewsave, redo, reset, save, tap, undo, wheel_zoom, xbox_select,
>   xbox_zoom, xpan, xwheel_pan, xwheel_zoom, xzoom_in, xzoom_out,
>   ybox_select, ybox_zoom, ypan, ywheel_pan, ywheel_zoom, yzoom_in,
>   yzoom_out, zoom_in, zoom_out

You can get a list of all possible options by just typing a non-existing one. The informative error message will give you a list of options to choose from. So just do:

```
hv.Scatter(df).opts(tools=['nonsense'])
```