# Turn off automatic interaction HoloViews / Bokeh charts in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter, bokeh, jupyter-lab, holoviews, datashader

How do I have the chart display without any engagement buttons clicked on?

Would like the top button (see picture), which is currently defaulting on, to default off.

[image: How to have this not automatically turn on?]

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415434/how-to-set-active-tools-in-holoviews and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992160/how-to-control-active-tools-in-holoviews-with-bokeh-backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Holoviews does not expose this option directly, so you have to define a custom hook which modifies the underlying bokeh model, it should look something like this:

```
def tools(plot, element):
    plot.handles['plot'].toolbar.active_drag = None

hv.Curve([]).opts(hooks=[tools])
```